# jquery ajaxform url parameters

Tags: jquery, parameters, ajaxform

sorry for stupid question...

i need to calculate the "url" parameter of a ajaxForm()...

i write something like this...

```
$('#form-domanda').ajaxForm({
    url: function() {
        id = $('#form-domanda input[name=domanda_id]').val()
        if (id > 0) {
            return "url-1.cfm"
        } else {
            return "url-2.cfm"
        }
    }
});
```

but url accept only string :-(

how can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're out of luck here. Sounds like you want to change the form's target based on the value of one of the form's elements; the value in question won't be known until after `ajaxForm` is bound to the form so Justin's trick won't work.

You could use the `beforeSubmit` or `beforeSerialize` hooks to change the `ajaxForm` URL but there's nothing in the API that lets you change the URL once `ajaxForm` has been bound. So, the hooks are of no use to you.

You could try adding a submit handler to the form; this handler would check the value of `#form-domanda input[name=domanda_id]` and then bind the appropriate `ajaxForm` to `#form-domanda` and call `$('#form-domanda').ajaxSubmit()` after the you've bound `ajaxForm`. This might work or it might not and quite frankly, this is a bit of a hack.

I think you'd be better off moving the `domanda_id` logic onto the server, either in `url-1.cfm` or whatever is generating the `#form-domanda` in the first place.

Comment: your are right... i'll change my server side script... many thanks!

Comment: Tks, it help me to solve this problem
   $('form#fileupload').ajaxSubmit({
            beforeSubmit: function(data, form, options) {
                options["url"] = "your url here"
            },
            success:function (data) {
                //do anything when success
            }
        });

Comment: @HuestonRido What problem? Perhaps you should ask a new question so that you have room to explain what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, to call the function immediately:

```
$('#form-domanda').ajaxForm({
url: function() {
    id = $('#form-domanda input[name=domanda_id]').val()
    if (id > 0) {
        return "url-1.cfm"
    } else {
        return "url-2.cfm"
    }()
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For reference, this works for me:

```
$('#form-domanda').ajaxForm({
    beforeSubmit: function(data, form, options) {
        id = form.find('input[name=domanda_id]').val();
        if (id > 0) {
            options["url"] = "url-1.cfm";
        } else {
            options["url"] = "url-2.cfm";
        }
    }
});
```